# hybris's maven doesn't download transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to set my dependencies in the external-dependencies.xml in Hybris extension. The problem is it just load the libraries I specified in there and doesn't load the dependencies that the libraries need to work with at run-time.

For example Aixs2-kernel loads Axiom-api and impl and adb and so on. And in a normal maven project I don't need to specify each of them one by one.

Is there any way to make Hybris understand to fetch the rest of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SAP Hybris 6.4+**

Yes, you can do this in by overwriting the `maven.download.options` parameter in an extension `project.properties` file. It's default value is equal to:

```
-DoverWriteReleases=true -DoverWriteSnapshots=true -DoverWriteIfNewer=true -DexcludeTransitive=true
```

If you add to your extension `project.properties` the line:

```
maven.download.options=-DoverWriteReleases=true -DoverWriteSnapshots=true -DoverWriteIfNewer=true
```

SAP Hybris platform will download all dependencies (also transitive). Of course this change will work only for your extension (please don't change content of the `project.properties` file located in core extensions).

---

**SAP Hybris 6.3 and older**

Exclusion of the transitive dependencies is hardcoded in the `hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/mavenTasks.xml` file (macro `updateLibFolder`). The only possible solution is to do a patch in SAP Hybris platform. You can change this code:

```
<artifact:mvn pom="@{dependencyFile}" fork="true" failonerror="true" mavenVersion="3.2.5">
    <arg value="dependency:copy-dependencies" />
    <arg value="-DoutputDirectory=@{libfolder}" />
    <arg value="-DoverWriteReleases=true" />
    <arg value="-DoverWriteSnapshots=true" />
    <arg value="-DoverWriteIfNewer=true" />
    <arg value="-DexcludeTransitive=true" />
</artifact:mvn>
```

to:

```
<artifact:mvn pom="@{dependencyFile}" fork="true" failonerror="true" mavenVersion="3.2.5">
    <arg line="dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=@{libfolder} ${maven.download.options}" />
    <jvmarg line="${env.MAVEN_OPTS} ${env.JAVA_OPTS}" />
</artifact:mvn>
```

next define a property

```
maven.download.options=-DoverWriteReleases=true -DoverWriteSnapshots=true -DoverWriteIfNewer=true
```

in the `hybris/bin/platform/project.properties` and finally do steps from the solution for 6.4+.

---

**Warning:** SAP Hybris platform provides a lot of libraries, so probably some of your transitive dependencies are already available. That is the reason, why downloading of the transitive dependencies are disabled. I think it is a good idea to specify them manually instead of downloading everything (you will avoid problems with the differences of the version).

Comment: It seems this solution may work for 6.5 and in 6.2 whatever I tried it didn't work.

Comment: I added a solution for 6.2, but still the safest idea is to specify all transitive dependencies manually.