# RestTemplateBuilder is failed when building

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sap-commerce-cloud

I created Rest Web service call using Rest Template and for basic authentication, I'm trying to use RestTemplateBuilder to build the basic authentication when sending request. I had given all spring boot dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Code:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
      .basicAuthorization("username", "password").build();
restTemplate.postForObject("rest webservice url",inputparam, XXX.Class);
```

But even after giving the dependency also, build is failing.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "build is failing" So, can you share the error message?

Comment: 1.ERROR in ERROR in C:\Hybris\..\..\......\...\XXXXXXXXX.java (at line 16)
 import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
 The import org.springframework.boot cannot be resolved
 2. ERROR in C:\Hybris\..\..\......\...\XXXXXXXXX.java (at line 39)
 private static RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;
RestTemplateBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
 3. ERROR in C:\Hybris\..\..\......\...\XXXXXXXXX.java (at line 52)
 final RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
 RestTemplateBuilder cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

You can create `RestTemplate` using `RestTemplateBuilder` like below.

```
@Service
public class ApiClient {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ApiClient(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        restTemplate = builder.basicAuthorization("username", "password").build();
    }

    //Other implementation details
}
```

And then can make calls to remote api with this `RestTemplate` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the dependency is not resolve, but I can tell you how I've resolved the problem in question.

First I have service for all my rest template functionalities:

```
@Service
@SuppressWarnings("squid:RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck")
public class RestTemplateService {

private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public RestTemplateService() {
    this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

public <T> T doGETRequestForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException {
    return restTemplate.getForObject(url, responseType);
}

public <T> T doGETRequestForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams) throws RestClientException {
    return restTemplate.getForObject(url, responseType, queryParams);
}

public <T> T doGETRequestForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams, Map<String, String> headerParams, MediaType... mediaTypes) throws RequestIsNotOKException {
    return doGETRequestForEntity(url, responseType, queryParams, headerParams, mediaTypes).getBody();
}

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doGETRequestForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, responseType);
    validateResponseStatus(entity);
    return entity;
}

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doGETRequestForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, responseType, queryParams);
    validateResponseStatus(entity);
    return entity;
}

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doGETRequestForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams, Map<String, String> headerParams, MediaType... mediaTypes) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, getHttpEntity(headerParams, mediaTypes, null), responseType, queryParams);
    validateResponseStatus(entity);
    return entity;
}

public HttpStatus doPOSTRequestForStatusCode(String url, Object requestBody) throws RestClientException {
    return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestBody, Void.class).getStatusCode();
}

public HttpStatus doPOSTRequestForStatusCode(String url, Object requestBody, Map<String, String> queryParams) throws RestClientException {
    return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestBody, Void.class, queryParams).getStatusCode();
}

public <T> T doPOSTRequestForObject(String url, Object requestBody, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    return restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestBody, responseType);
}

public <T> T doPOSTRequestForObject(String url, Object requestBody, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams) throws RestClientException {
    return restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestBody, responseType, queryParams);
}

public <T> T doPOSTRequestForObject(String url, Object requestBody, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams, Map<String, String> headerParams, MediaType... mediaTypes) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    return doPOSTRequestForEntity(url, requestBody, responseType, queryParams, headerParams, mediaTypes).getBody();
}

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doPOSTRequestForEntity(String url, Object requestBody, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestBody, responseType);
    validateResponseStatus(entity);
    return entity;
}

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doPOSTRequestForEntity(String url, Object requestBody, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestBody, responseType, queryParams);
    validateResponseStatus(entity);
    return entity;
}

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doPOSTRequestForEntity(String url, Object requestBody, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, String> queryParams, Map<String, String> headerParams, MediaType... mediaTypes) throws RestClientException, RequestIsNotOKException {
    ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, getHttpEntity(headerParams, mediaTypes, requestBody), responseType, queryParams);
    validateResponseStatus(entity);
    return entity;
}

private HttpEntity getHttpEntity(Map<String, String> headerParams, MediaType[] mediaTypes, Object requestBody) {
    return aHttpEntity()
             .withHeaderParams(headerParams)
             .withMediaTypes(mediaTypes)
             .withBody(requestBody)
             .build();
}

public <T> void validateResponseStatus(ResponseEntity<T> entity) throws RequestIsNotOKException {
    if (HttpStatus.OK.equals(entity.getStatusCode())) {
        throw new RequestIsNotOKException(entity);
    }
}

public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return restTemplate;
}

public static class RequestIsNotOKException extends Exception {

    private final ResponseEntity entity;

    public RequestIsNotOKException(ResponseEntity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public ResponseEntity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

}

then if I want to pass basic authentication I have static method from util class for encoding

```
public static String encodeToBase64(String separator, String... parameters) {
    validateNonNulls(parameters);

    if (isBlank(separator)) {
        separator = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    return encodeToBase64(join(parameters, separator));
}

public static String encodeToBase64(String strToEncode) {
    byte[] encodedStr = Base64.encodeBase64(strToEncode.getBytes());
    return new String(encodedStr);
}
```

And now you can pass your encoded usr/pass to service method which will build you HttpHeader and Entity -- btw I use small builder for parameters maps of all kinds...

```
... paramsMap = anParametersMap().withEntry("Authorization", encodeToBase64(":", usr, pass)).build()

restTemplateService.doPOSTRequestForObject("rest webservice url",requestBody, XXX.Class, null, paramsMap, null);
```

btw you can accomplish all of this by adding BasicAuthorizationInterceptor to restTemplate interceptors but I didn't go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris doesn't download transitive dependencies by default, so not all required libraries are downloaded (dependencies of dependencies). You have to specify them all or enable downloading transitive dependencies. Read how to do it here: [hybris's maven doesn't download transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46599669/4944847).